# Compare dynamic text in Cypress

Tags: cypress, gettext

I have an online store that I'm testing with Cypress.
There is the total price of the cart, and each article has a price. 
I want to check  that when you click on a article, the total price goes up by article price. 
Example: 
total price = 100. 
article price = 20

check that when click on article, total price is 120

How to do that when I have a list of 10 articles? that each time you click on one article, the total price goes up by the correct amount?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use variable with `each` method.

It should looks something like this:

```
let sum = 0;

cy.get('items').each(item => {
  sum += +item.text;
});
```

Then on end ot the test just call:

```
cy.get('total').should('contains', sum);
```

[Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Syntax)